# SetInterval is calling 5 time at same time in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, background-task

I am using library `react-native-background-timer` which I am running some tasks in background . Actually this function is working fine but when I console it in render method, it firing this function 5 times at same time . I just want to call one time . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';
```

in render method:

```
 BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => console.log('@@@@ data has been rendered'), 60000);
 BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(6000)
```

Comment: are you sure you need `setInterval` and not `setTimeout`?

Comment: also, how many time did the render got called? this will be re-inititated at each render phase

Comment: @Itamar it actually called more then 18 time ? I just want to call it one time ( in one minute )

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Found your answer yet?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this particular library, but [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) usually takes an ID to the [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) that should be cleared, and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) would return an ID.

```
 const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => console.log('@@@@ data has been rendered'), 60000);
 BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(intervalHandle);
```

[render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) is probably not the method to use for this unless you are using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Consider using other [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) methods. I suggest using [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)() for calling the setInterval() and [componentWillUnmount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) for the clearInterval().

Comment: This is almost certainly the issue. The docs show this usage https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer#android

Comment: I just edit my code , not it firing console.log 18 times

Comment: [Wed Sep 16 2020 01:49:43.566]  LOG      @@@@ data has been rendered
[Wed Sep 16 2020 01:49:43.568]  LOG      @@@@ data has been rendered

Comment: It's getting called every time that `render()` is called.

Comment: @Slbox Actually, I want to call my function after every 1 minute but I want to fire it one time . Now it firing more then 18 time at same time .

Comment: @JonasDev then you need to place the `setInterval` logic _outside_ of `render()` (or use the `useEffect` hook.) See @Itamar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the comment, which i think is the real need here:

> it actually called more then 18 time ? I just want to call it one time ( in one minute )

If you need to run a background task **once** on component load, you need to choose one of the following:

- Class component `componentDidMount()` life cycle
- Function component `useEffect` hook

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-cloud-dgw8g?file=/src/App.js

### Class Component

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("A running");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 60000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> Hey from A </div>;
  }
}
```

### Function Component

```js
function B() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("B running");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 60000);
  }, []); // <- empty array to run only on first render

  return <div> Hey from B </div>;
}
```